# Android : Google Speech Streaming APi

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-developers-console

Hey i need a Help on google Streaming Cloud Speech Api if someone use that things. i am getting fast response when i have good network connectivity but in bad network it is not working fine.Sometimes it takes time to give error(Error:low Streaming) and sometimes it takes time to response. i was also trying Default Android Speech Api run simultaneously so that i can get user text. but it allow only one between AudioRecord or Recognize Intent run at one time to listen and through network error in Android Speech. So how to handle Speech Cloud api with local Speech listener So that i can get User Speech text even in low bandwidth or if google Speech Api through any error ?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Speech API works well when a minimum level of input quality is maintained. You may find more detail on the minimum requirements on the "Best Practices" documenation [page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices).
You may avoid errors by keeping track of the following following sub-fields in the StreamingRecognitionResult: "alternative", "isFinal" and "stability". Details are offered on the "Cloud Speech-to-Text Basics" [page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#streaming_responses).

Comment: Thanks this links covers lots of things and i already did that. But  main questions i m in low network like hills area in 2G network speed app like Google Assistant prints user Speech to text even in low network like 2G where Cloud Speech Api through Error:(StreamErr:OUT_OF_RANGE: Audio data is being streamed too slow). google assistant also using same Cloud Api . how they print User Speech to text. i used Speech Recognition Api with Cloud but Audio and RecognitionIntent but only one can get access of microphone at one time.  What Api i can use simultaneously to get text from speech.

Comment: One cannot make abstraction of the need to fulfill the minimum requirements on the "Best Practices" documenation [page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices).